# How to read response body from SimpleHttpOperator

Tags: airflow

I am new to Airflow. I have written a code to submit HTTP Post using SimpleHttpOperator. In this case post request return a token, i need a help on how reading the response body.

```
get_templates = SimpleHttpOperator(
    task_id='get_templates',
    method='POST',
    endpoint='myendpoint',
    http_conn_id = 'myconnection',
    trigger_rule="all_done",
    headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    xcom_push=True,
    dag=dag
)
```

Looks like POST was successful. Now my question is how to read the response body.
This is the output of code, there is no errors
[2019-05-06 20:08:40,518] {http_hook.py:128} INFO - Sending 'POST' to url: https://auth.reltio.com/oauth//token?username=perf_api_user&password=perf_api_user!&grant_type=password
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:847: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)

Answer (score 3):

The `execute` function of the `SimpleHttpOperator` returns the `response.text` ([source](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/e62ad5333cbb56ae0f2001f0f79008a21c41a983/airflow/operators/http_operator.py#L94)). By looking at the [Airflow documentation for XCom](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#xcoms), you can see that:

> ... if a task returns a value (either from its Operator’s execute() method, or from a PythonOperator’s python_callable function), then an XCom containing that value is automatically pushed.

meaning the response body is pushed to the XCom and is available for downstream tasks to access.

For example, you could have a `PythonOperator` fetching it via:

```py
response_body = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(task_ids='get_templates')
```

Additionally, if you just want to log the response instead of process it, you can just set the `log_response` of the `SimpleHttpOperator` constructor to `True`.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried and i am getting below error. Do i need to import some library response_body = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(task_ids='get_templates')
NameError: name 'context' is not defined

Comment: I was able to pull the response_body. One of the element of the response body is token which i need to pass to next SimpleHttpOperator task.  Something like as below  headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token}. Can you help me with that.

Comment: You just return the value from your function, it will get sent to the XCom in the same way. Do the same thing in the next operator as you did here to retrieve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Airflow 2 `xcom_push` argument is not available in SimpleHttpOperator. In this case let's say you call `/my-url` in task `call_api`; to get the response and pass it to another task you need to read from the xcom `return_value` that is automatically defined by the `SimpleHttpOperator` as:

```
call_api = SimpleHttpOperator(
    task_id='call_api',
    http_conn_id=api_connection,
    method='GET',
    endpoint='/my-url',
    response_filter=lambda response: json.loads(response.text),
    log_response=True,  # Shows response in the task log
    dag=dag
)

def _read_response(ti):
    val = ti.xcom_pull(
        task_ids='call_api',
        key='return_value'
    )
    print(val)


read_response = PythonOperator(
    task_id='read_response',
    python_callable=_read_response,
    dag=dag
)
```

You can also specify `dag_id` in `ti.xcom_pull` to select the running dag.

Comment: For me this answer solved my problems. Also an alternative approach ```response_filter=lambda response: response.json()``` to get the whole response object